Windows button not visible on title bar of Windows Flutter Desktop App
I am building a Flutter Desktop app for Windows. When in light mode the app bar buttons and title are visible but when we change the theme to dark mode the title bar appears white/black with no buttons available but when we tap on their position it works like it is supposed to.
By default the flutter app is in light theme. I am using the windows_manager package as well to setup my desktop configuration.
I am unable to figure out why this happens and how I can fix this.
My RCA:
When we open the app and dark mode is enabled, then title bar color is black and buttons are white and when we change it to light then title bar color remains black but button colors change to black to match the theme and vice-versa for light mode.

Set the Transparent Title Bar and Handle it Manually, use the Window Manager plugin to hide it manually. add this manually using the code below.
await windowManager.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden);


We can do this to hide the title bar but I want to show the title bar with the windows button.
